# My output only shows wrong even though it is correct

Tags: python-3.x, passwords

I don't see why it only displays wrong it only displays the last line it worked when it used the username and password in the script?

```
def login():

 for username in range(3):
   username = input("Enter your username:")
   password = input("Enter your password:")


   d="example1"
   k="example2"
   s="school"

   f=open("bob.txt")
   lines=f.readlines()

   if username == lines[0] and password == lines[1]:
        print("welcome to soar valley",d)
        break
    
   if username == lines[2] and password ==lines[3]:
        print("welcome to soar valley",s)
        break

   if username == lines[4] and password ==lines[5]:
        print("welcome to soar valley",k)
        break

   if username or password != lines[0] or lines[1] or lines[2]or lines[3]or
   lines[4] or lines[5]:
        print("wrong try again")


login()
```

Comment: I think this does not do what you want it to do: `if username or password != lines[0] or lines[1] or lines[2]or lines[3]or
   lines[4] or lines[5]`. You can't just translate word for word from English.

Answer (score 0):

You misused the operator `or`.

`if username or password != lines[0] or lines[1] or lines[2]or lines[3]or
   lines[4] or lines[5]:`

This line is not executed as what you was expected.

[In the Python 3.7 documentation of `or`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#or),

> the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

So, a not-empty string is always interpreted as `True`, which means your target line can be simplified under the supposed condition (username and password are not empty, and the file "bob.txt" contains at least 6 non-empty lines at the beginning):

`if True or True != True or True or True or True or
  True or True:`

Which become always true. And this is exactly what you don't expected.

For your situation, you may try the keyword [`not in`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

`if username not in lines[0:5] and password not in lines[0:5]:`

Better to use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to make a username-password pair.

Comment: What have you typed and what output you seen lets you know it 'still don't work'?

Comment: usually if the password is correct it should output "welcome to soar valley" but what it actually outputs is "wrong try again"